# PHP into Native Android app

Tags: php, apk

I was wondering if it is possible to turn my PHP, MySQL project into a Native Android App (.apk)?

I did a research about the topic, but I didn't find a straight answer.

Any opinion or idea?

Br,

Comment: you should start a project using the right language. there are tools for converting some languages in to others, but the never do a very good job.

Comment: ask a programming question, not a disscusion for alternative tools

Answer (score 1):

Bad Idea but here is how to achieve it:

### Local APP

- Change mysql to sqlite3;
- Create an Android service listening in a port;
- Ship an php interpreter along with your app;
- Create an Android Webview Activity.

Have your battery drained in 5 minutes while using the app.

### Remote APP

- Make a web app and host it on your server;
- Create an Android Webview Activity.

### Clean way

- Make a responsive web app that works for both desktop and mobile;
- Use the mobile browser.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't simply turn your web application into a native Android App.
But you can do this:

### Backend:

1. Create some REST-like API, so you can get data in JSON or XML.
2. Deploy your web app and configure your server so it can accept remote requests.

### Frontend:

1. IF you don't want to learn Kotlin or Java use one of frameworks which allow you to use JS to create native (almost) apps for mobile platforms (e.g. React Native)
2. IF you don't want to learn any framework either you can create a WebView activity as was adviced before

Good luck!